# При переносе проекта возникает ошибка System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0

Tags: c#, postgresql

Запускаю проект на другой машине, проект скачан из репозитория, все ссылки работают, связи все правильные, через gacutil добавил несколько сборок, но  при компиляции возникает ошибка.

```
DevExpress.Xpo.DB.Exceptions.UnableToOpenDatabaseException: "Нельзя открыть базу данных. Строка подключения: 'User Id=postgres;Password=***REMOVED***;Host=localhost;Database=test;Pooling=False;Integrated Security=False;Enlist=False;'; Ошибка:'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.
Имя файла: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   в System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_IsCompleted()
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Authenticate>d__0.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__149.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   в DevExpress.Xpo.DB.PostgreSqlConnectionProvider.CreateDataBase()

=== Информация о состоянии предварительной привязки ===
Журнал: DisplayName = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
Журнал: Appbase = file:///D:/Piter/EnergyEfficiency-dev/EnergyEfficiency-dev/DemoEE-2/Energy.Win/bin/Debug/
Журнал: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Вызов сборки: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
===
Журнал: данная привязка начинается в контексте загрузки default.
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации приложения: D:\Piter\EnergyEfficiency-dev\EnergyEfficiency-dev\DemoEE-2\Energy.Win\bin\Debug\Energy.Win.exe.Config.
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации главного узла: 
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации компьютера из C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
Журнал: ссылка после применения политики: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Журнал: данная привязка встречалась ранее и закончилась ошибкой hr = 0x80070002.
'"
```

Эту сборку я добавил  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0 но увы описанные в интернете методы не помогают 
Сделал еще раз добавление сборки.

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.0.3
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Windows\System32>where System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll

C:\Windows\System32>gacutil /i C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
c Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

Неизвестный параметр: Files

C:\Windows\System32>gacutil /i d:\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
c Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

Сборка успешно добавлена в кэш

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: `Нельзя открыть базу данных. Строка подключения: '...Host=localhost` ?

Comment: Все верно в строке база работает база постгрес.

Comment: в строке ничего не может работать, это же строка. У вас база локально установлена? Подключение к ней работает?

Comment: Да все прекрасно работает

Comment: В логе пишется .что  Ошибка:'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл. Но у меня сборки добавлены в Gac. А все равно сборка не видна

Comment: версия и ключ сборки совпадают? Фреймворк установлен нужной версии? Просто сборку пробовали в пвпку с приложением кидать?

Comment: фреймворк совпадает, сборки совпадают. А файл не копировал попробую